# How can LWC pass on the data to the omniscript

Tags: lightning-web-components, omnistudio

The omniscript is embedded in the LWC.

At the load of the omniscript inside the LWC i have already used the prefill parameter.

But once I put up some data in the omniscript there is button on the lwc wrapper which aggregates the data from omniscript and pass on to server for validation.

The warnings/errors needs to be displayed at the field level inside the omniscript. I am not getting the way where I can pass on the data from LWC to Omniscript here.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?
we bump in the same problem